# %PATH% on Windows 2008 Server actually not working

Tags: path, cmd, windows-server-2008

As you can see below, `%AppData%\npm` is added in the system Path variable. I've also tried adding it to the User Path variable. The file `grunt.cmd` exists in the directory, but only works if I specify it with an absolute path. AKA, path does not work.

```
C:\Users\TeamCity>echo %path%
%AppData%\npm;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows
\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\10
0\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program F
iles\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Ser
ver\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Ser
ver\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program
Files\nodejs\

C:\Users\TeamCity>dir %appdata%\npm
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B845-1135

 Directory of C:\Users\TeamCity\AppData\Roaming\npm

05/29/2013  03:14 AM    <DIR>          .
05/29/2013  03:14 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/29/2013  03:14 AM               298 grunt
05/29/2013  03:14 AM               159 grunt.cmd
05/29/2013  03:13 AM    <DIR>          node_modules
               2 File(s)            457 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  23,690,498,048 bytes free

C:\Users\TeamCity>grunt
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\TeamCity>%appdata%\npm\grunt
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.9)
```

Running on:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
- Service Pack 1
- 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can defer variable expansion in the path. What's in the path is used as is, it doesn't get re-interpreted during a search.

In fact, you must have worked really hard to get that in as `%AppData%` since you would need to do something like:

```
path=^%AppData^%\npm;%path%
```

If you were to just use:

```
path=%AppData%\npm;%path%
```

you'd find the actual path would be substituted, so that the path becomes:

```
C:\Users\TeamCity\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Windows\system32; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, a last-ditch effort of "turning it off and on again" actually worked. Alternatively, you can copy the whole path after you added it and type in cmd:

```
> SET PATH=
```

and paste your path.